# Is this the place to ask Geonames questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I need to know how Geonames data dumps can be used to create a hierarchy like their webservice API provides. Is this site the place to ask this sort of question?

I will of course make a fuller, proper question if I'm in the right place !

EDIT: Of course the question goes on the site proper, rather than the meta...

Answer (score 4):

How to effectively use spatial data, especially from a broadly available public source, is on topic.

Modulo the usual stuff on asking good quesions, providing context, covering what doesn't work or what provokes confusion, etc.